# How can I strip out urls from a string in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to strip out urls from results of a SQL query.  All urls look like `http://` so no complex regex is necessary. But the urls can be anywhere in the string.

Examples:

```
alpha beta http://alphabeta.com/abc
gamma http://gammadel.com/def delta
http://epsilo.com/ghi epsilon theta
```

How can I strip these urls from my results to get the following?

```
alpha beta
gamma delta
epsilon theta
```

Notes:

1. URLs (in my use case) *do* always start with `http://`.
2. Only one URL is found per string
3. Ideally solutions will not require additional libraries

Comment: Is there only one url per line or may be multiple urls?

Comment: Good question. Only one per string. I'll add that to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about

```
SELECT REPLACE(
  'alpha gamma http://gammadel.com/def delta beta', 
  CONCAT('http://', 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
      SUBSTRING_INDEX('alpha gamma http://gammadel.com/def delta beta', 'http://', -1),' ', 1)
  ),''
);
```

I've tested it for strings that you provided, but not sure if it meets fully your requirements.

Basically what this code does is:

1. extract URL with `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` function
2. replace URL with empty string in the original string.

Here's a full query to test each scenario:

```
SET @str1="foo bar http://foobar.com/abc";
SET @str2="foo http://foobar.com/def bar";
SET @str3="http://foobar.com/ghi foo bar";
SELECT
    REPLACE(
        @str1, 
        CONCAT('http://', 
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                SUBSTRING_INDEX(@str1, 'http://', -1),
                ' ', 1
            )
        ),''
    ) AS str1,
    REPLACE(
        @str2, 
        CONCAT('http://', 
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                SUBSTRING_INDEX(@str2, 'http://', -1),
                ' ', 1
            )
        ),''
    ) AS str2,
    REPLACE(
        @str3, 
        CONCAT('http://', 
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                SUBSTRING_INDEX(@str3, 'http://', -1),
                ' ', 1
            )
        ),''
    ) AS str3
;
```

Returns (as expected) :

```
foo bar
foo bar
foo bar
```

Comment: This is a nice alternative to the solution I provided as it solves the problem without installing a library, which OP didn't ideally want to do. **+1**

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping for! Well done. Added my test query to see it all in action. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As you cannot use functions like `preg_replace` without having any addons/libraries - and as you've only tagged your question with `mysql`/`sql`, you're going to need to install this to give you the ability to use a regular expression replace. https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg#readme

Now that's installed, you can run;

```
SELECT CONVERT( 
   preg_replace('/(http:\/\/[^ \s]+)/i', '', foo)  
USING UTF8) AS result 
FROM `bar`;
```

This will give results like: https://regex101.com/r/qX6jB8/1

Comment: Hmmm... So it's not possible to strip a substring from `http:// to end or next space position?

Comment: Unless you use a bunch of functions to get string positions then *maybe*. Alternatively, you could strip the URLs out before you display them to your end-user after getting them from the database.

Comment: Hmmmm. +1 for something new for me :)

Comment: Thanks. I'm reticent to add a library to MySQL to solve this. But will come back to this if I'm unable to accomplish this another way.

Answer (score 0):

+1 to Jakub (+10 for functionality, -9 for enjoyability) for his answer.  I'm posting this derived abomination of his answer so I don't lose it, and may save hours of someone's time.

Take a part number field of varchar(255) and concat with a description field of varchar(255), trim, strip links, strip new lines, prevent part number from being duplicated in the description, and format it for insert into 2 char(30) fields that are concat...

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(
    TRIM(CONCAT(
        CONCAT(
            TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
                pi.part_number, CONCAT('https://', SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(pi.part_number, 'https://', -1), ' ', 1)), ''
            ), CONCAT('http://', SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(pi.part_number, 'http://', -1), ' ', 1)), ''), '\n', ''), '\r', ''))
            , ' '
        ),
        TRIM(REPLACE(
            REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
                pi.description, CONCAT('https://', SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(pi.description, 'https://', -1), ' ', 1)), ''
            ), CONCAT('http://', SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(pi.description, 'http://', -1), ' ', 1)), ''), '\n', ''), '\r', ''),
            TRIM(pi.part_number), ''
        ))
    ))
    , 1, 30
) AS PDDSC1,
SUBSTRING(
    TRIM(CONCAT(
        CONCAT(
            TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
                pi.part_number, CONCAT('https://', SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(pi.part_number, 'https://', -1), ' ', 1)), ''
            ), CONCAT('http://', SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(pi.part_number, 'http://', -1), ' ', 1)), ''), '\n', ''), '\r', ''))
            , ' '
        ),
        TRIM(REPLACE(
            REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
                pi.description, CONCAT('https://', SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(pi.description, 'https://', -1), ' ', 1)), ''
            ), CONCAT('http://', SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(pi.description, 'http://', -1), ' ', 1)), ''), '\n', ''), '\r', ''),
            TRIM(pi.part_number), ''
        ))
    ))
    , 31, 30
) AS PDDSC2
FROM purchase_request_items pi
```